# Use WSO2 Identity Server with Apache Httpd mod_auth_mellon

Tags: apache, wso2, single-sign-on, saml

I want to use the Apache Webserver 2.4 as ServiceProvider with mod_auth_mellon (SAML). As identity provider I am using WSO2 Identity Server. Can anybody help how to pair those two? Has anybody experience?

Answer (score 1):

see https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon; you would put the path to the metadata file obtained from the WSO2 identity server in the directive MellonIdPMetadataFile